# How to change default keyboard shortcuts for SSMS

Tags: sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

I would like to assign my stored procedures for shortcuts `CTRL+1` or `CTRL+2` which are reserved by default to `sp_who` or `sp_lock` procedures.

[image]

How to change shortcut for Ctrl+1

Comment: Why? As you have discovered those two options are reserved. So what? Why can't you just use any of the other available options?

Comment: check updated ans.

Comment: Why does that user wants what he wants, curse on him! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just Go - > Tools -> Options as below :

[image]

Check below :

[image]

Comment: Yeah, go ahead, please change shortcut for `Ctrl+1` and show the screenshot again.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin as per you need you could change the default shortcut from here.

Comment: I can't change it. I have SSMS 2016.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS go

> Tool > Options > Keyboard

you can alter the shortcuts in there, if you enter the shortcut in the 'Press shortcut keys:' box it will show you what its assigned to at the minute and you can choose from the list or add another

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. I know where shortcuts are. I ask about `CTRL+1` shortcut.

Comment: I'm not sure you can change those two, they are reserved. Are all your others full?